# The salary calculator is broken for some non-US countries

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I live in France, so I tried the [recently announced](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/10/international-salaries/) calculator for international salaries.

The result is *completely broken*.

So for a developer **without any experience** and the **lowest possible skill** one could have, you (because I understand the calculator returns what SO as a company would pay me if I worked for you) would pay me **68k€** ? 
It's literally ***twice*** what a typical company would pay.

I don't even talk about the default "1 year experience, 1.0 skill" values that returns **75.6k€** (if I'm lucky enough, I might expect this salary when I'll retire).

You might want to fix those values, the calculator is currently pointless, or worse (at least for my country).

Comment: We are just not a "typical company". :)

Comment: @Max Okay, but do you _actually_ have employees that live in my country? The numbers this calculator returns are indeed _far_ from typical (I mean here: _ridiculously high_). Even if I've worked for Google, I would have earned roughly 60% of that amount. And I'm talking about the capital (Paris). Here were I work (second city of the country), one could expect 32k€ (instead of 75.6).

Comment: Yup: http://stackoverflow.com/company/team

Comment: Are you talking about gross or net salary @ken2k? I've heard that the French government takes quite a lot in taxes, but that might be the US media playing tricks with me again...

Comment: http://disq.us/p/1cp1iw0 - TL;DR: Yes, these salaries refer to Stack Overflow employees only. They are gross salaries (for international contractors at least). And yes, the countries that appear in that list are the ones where Stack Overflow has at least one employee.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm talking about gross salary. If you remove taxes etc,  for example the net amount I currently earn is ~27k€.

Comment: 27k? Nice. In Germany, 32k becomes about 20.5k after taxes and social security.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The calculator describes our pay scale, for Stack Overflow employees. We’ve seen confusion that it represents general industry rates, which it does not.

We changed some copy: the header is now “How We Pay” and not merely “Salary Calculator”. Inherent in those numbers is “if you got hired at Stack Overflow”, which is a high bar.

Comment: I got that part. Doesn't answer my question though. Or the answer would be: "we pay twice what the second best company would pay you".

Comment: `Or the answer would be: "we pay twice what the second best company would pay you"` Apparently that is the answer. Although I'm having a hard time believing IT salaries in France are *that* low everywhere. It appears you can get much more in Germany, if salary calculators online can be trusted - and the two neighbours shouldn't be that far off. Might depend a lot on where you work (both geographically and in terms of industry and company size)?

Comment: @ken2k I don’t know whether we pay twice what other companies do, but if we stipulate what you say about other companies, then the answer is “yes”.

Comment: Also note that it's gross pay (i.e. before taxes) and in most countries where we don't have a presence we hire contractors, which mean all business taxes are born by the employee.